# rsync - how to exclude a specific file or group of files (e.g. *.log) from being transferred

Tags: rsync

I do not want log files (`*.log`) to be sent, and do not want them deleted on the target system.
However, if a directory is to be deleted on the target because it's not on the sender; and it has a log file, I want the directory and included log files to be deleted.  I have `--exclude "*.log"` in my rsync command.
I've been searching through the online man pages, and am now examining the more advanced `--filter options`.

Thanks,
Jimmy

Comment: What's the exact comand you're using? The exclude setting should, on the surface, do almost exactly what you want. Possibly a bit of tweaking with the delete options but need to see the exact command first

Comment: "_However, if a directory is to be deleted on the target because it's not on the sender; and it has a log file, I want the directory and included log files to be deleted_" - what should happen if (a) the selected directory contains no log files, (b) the selected directory contains files (or directories) other than log files?

Comment: Current command is:    rsync -a --dry-run --verbose --delete-before --exclude=kl '--include=.vim**' --include=.profile '--include=.bash**' --exclude '*.log' --exclude=nas/amc.log '--exclude=nas/*/*' '--exclude=/.*' '--exclude=*.gz' '--exclude=VirtualBox VMs' --exclude=cache --exclude=.cache --exclude=.Trash-1000 --progress --size-only --modify-window=1 --times --min-size=1 --one-file-system --hard-links --executability ./ mint:./
if (a) the selected directory contains no log files, DELETE(b) the selected directory contains files (or directories) other than log files? DELETE  Out of post chars

Comment: Have tried various combos of --delete-xxxx.  Am using this to sync my two pcs of course, and always dry-run first to see expected results.  Then run in opposite direction.  I did --exclude="*.log" so logs wouldn't be sent, and surprised a bit when seeing that "protects" the log files on target from being deleted.  My wish was for log files to never be changed, except if in a deleted directory; i.e. the directory does not exist on sender.  Not sure I'm making sense here.

Comment: This is a bit weird. rsync is mostly in transparency. So if you don't want to send logfiles to the target, why are some there then? Excluding files means "ignore them". On both sender and reciever.

Comment: Let me try to clarify.  I am trying to sync filesystems.  Some files and directories are unique to each system; e.g. logs, cache, vbox, the "." files in home dir, etc  I tried to protect them with the excludes and explicitly include some of them with includes; e.g. .vim.  BUT, if a directory is being deleted on receiver because it is not on sender, I want that directory deleted, even if it has a protected file in it.